# 2sxc | Duplicate an existing App

Tags: 2sxc

I want to duplicate an existing app but run into errors when doing so. I am able to rename an app just fine (both in file structure and app configuration screen) but after renaming and importing same app again it throws error.

I have tried importing FAQ app, renaming it (successfully), exporting this renamed app, then re importing FAQ app again, and trying to import my custom exported app into the new FAQ app but due to existing uploaded content it fails?

What is the best practice to duplicate an existing app? Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is a rare scenario and there's a feature request to do this, but ATM you'll have to do it manually. These are the "pain points":

1. folder where the app is
2. app GUID

Since this is a rare scenario, I would

1. quickly import the app into another portal
2. change the app-folder in the DNN file management
3. change the app-folder in the app-settings
4. export the app again - and make sure you check the box "reset GUID" as it will set the GUID to 00000-0000-... which will make the import generate a new guid for you

Hope this helps.